# Number of digits setting for serial printing the sensor output value

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, data

I am getting fan motor rpm as 3200. But if I get the data as 50, I should get the value like 0050. How can I do this?

I can do it like checking the value for single digit(0-9), double digit (10-99), and triple digit (100-999) and four digit(1000-9999). I need to fix digit size and send it through serial. Is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the C function `sprintf`:

```
char text[5];
sprintf(text, "%04d", number);
Serial.println(text);
```

The leading 0 in 04d will add zero's for the length (4) is met, so 1 will become 0001, 10 will become 0010, 100 will become 0100 and 1000 will stay 1000.

Comment: this is what i expected... thank you very much for your comment..

Comment: Why char text[5]; ? Why 5 is entered?? Why not 4 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

Three if statements look a bit simplistic, but are much better in code size than `sprintf`, if that's the only usage for sprintf.

```
 if (number < 1000) Serial.write('0');
 if (number < 100) Serial.write('0');
 if (number < 10) Serial.write('0');
 Serial.println(number);
```

Saves about 1.5kB Flash, compiled with Arduino 1.8.9 for an Uno

Comment: if      (number <   10) { Serial.print("000"); }
    else if (number <  100) { Serial.print("00"); }
    else if (number < 1000) { Serial.print('0'); } 
This saves another 200 bytes.